# how to get my friend list along with all users with is_friend column value 0 1

Tags: mysql, join, exists, mysql-8.0

I am having trouble listing my friend list along with all users

I used this statement to list all the friend list of user_id 1 :

```
SELECT users.user_id, username, full_name, avatar, user_type, last_active FROM users JOIN user_active ua on users.user_id = ua.user_id WHERE users.user_id IN( (SELECT user_id1 FROM friends WHERE user_id2 = 1) UNION (SELECT user_id2 FROM friends WHERE user_id1 = 1)) AND users.status = 1;
```

I can also use this statement to find friend list of user_id 1 along with all people but there is now way to identify who is my or who is not in my friend list:

```
SELECT users.user_id, username, full_name, avatar, user_type, last_active FROM users JOIN user_active ua on users.user_id = ua.user_id WHERE users.user_id IN( (SELECT user_id1 FROM friends WHERE user_id2 = 1) UNION (SELECT user_id2 FROM friends WHERE user_id1 = 1)) OR users.user_id != 1  AND users.status = 1;
```

details of friends table:

```
+------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+-----------------+
|Field       |Type           |Null|Key|Default          |Extra            |
+------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+-----------------+
|f_request_id|bigint unsigned|NO  |PRI|NULL             |auto_increment   |
|user_id1    |bigint         |NO  |   |NULL             |                 |
|user_id2    |bigint         |NO  |   |NULL             |                 |
|created_at  |timestamp      |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|DEFAULT_GENERATED|
+------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+-----------------+
```

if you guys can help me add an extra column on the result like is_friend with value containing 0 or 1, 0 for nor friend 1 for friend, I will be very grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the friends table, user_id2 is a friend of user_id1? Or is this table just a list of friend "requests"?  I think your table design might need some clarity.

Comment: @Phaelaxz  user_id1 is friend of user_id2 vice-versa. AND here f_request_id is used to store which friend request got accepted from friend_requests table. I have set trigger to automatically populate this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT` join of `users` to `friends`:

```
SELECT u.*, 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(f.user_id1, ?), f.user_id2) IS NOT NULL is_friend
FROM users u LEFT JOIN friends f
ON u.user_id IN (f.user_id1, f.user_id2) AND ? IN (f.user_id1, f.user_id2)
WHERE u.user_id <> ? AND u.status = 1;
```

Change the 3 occurrences of the placeholder `?` to the id of the user you want to get the results.

If you get duplicate results because the table `friends` may contain 2 rows for the same *friendship* (like (1,2) and (2,1)) then use `SELECT DISTINCT u.* ....`.

Or, use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.*, 
       EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM friends f 
         WHERE u.user_id IN (f.user_id1, f.user_id2) AND ? IN (f.user_id1, f.user_id2)
       ) is_friend
FROM users u 
WHERE u.user_id <> ? AND u.status = 1;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1dabb7cc471543af4330ded578d254c).